# How to increase load time on docker with nginx and php7-fpm on local machine

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

On my local machine, WordPress Page load time is very slow on docker with nginx and php7-fpm and in network call its shows 2 - 4 sec to load first doc. but when I calculate PHP execution time it shows me 0.02 - 0.1 sec. how can I optimize docker setup to speed up the local environment?

below are some details of my local environment

My Local Environment is set up on Mac Sierra and I run the docker by

`docker-compose up -d`

and here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dummy
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dummy
      - MYSQL_USER=dummy
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dummy
    volumes:
      - dummy_path/dump.sql.gz:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql1.sql.gz
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - mysql:db
      - php
    volumes:
      - dummy_path:/app/www
      - dummy_path/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - dummy_path/nginx/ssl:/etc/ssl/
      - dummy_path/nginx/nginx.conf/:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - dummy_path/hosts:/etc/hosts
  php:
    container_name: php
    image: droidhive/php-memcached
    links:
      - mysql:db
      - memcached
    volumes:
      - dummy_path:/app/www
      - dummy_path/php/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - dummy_path/hosts:/etc/hosts
  memcached:
    container_name: memcached
    image: memcached
    volumes:
      - dummy_path:/app/www
```

Comment: It'd help a lot if we were able to see how you start the docker containers and it'd help a lot to see what's inside the nginx configuration. Otherwise expect generic/unrelated answers or simply downvotes.

Comment: Are you using Mac or Linux for the host machine? Are you mounting any volumes when you run Wordpress/Docker? Could you post your Dockerfile, the `docker run` command you're using, and the `docker-compose.yml` file (if you have one)?

Comment: @Stefano have I have run it by `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: @karllhughes updated the question's description

Comment: I know there is a bug with docker for mac. The files read from mounted volumes are very very slow. You are in this case. Can you put your app files directly in the image, instead of mounting them in the container?

Comment: You can now add `:cached` to the volume lines to improve this speed issue. [Here are the docs on it](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would try is to update your Dockerfile to `ADD` or `COPY` all your files into each image rather than mounting them as volumes. @fiber-optic mentioned this in the comments, but the new Dockerfile for your PHP container would be something like this:

```
FROM droidhive/php-memcached
ADD dummy_path:/app/www
ADD dummy_path/php/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
ADD dummy_path/hosts:/etc/hosts
```

Do this for at least the PHP container, but the MySQL container might also be an issue.

If that doesn't help or you can't get it to work, try adding `:ro` or `:cached` to each of your volumes.

`:ro` means "read-only", which allows your container to assume the volume won't change. Obviously this won't work if you need to do local dev with the code in a volume, but for some of your configuration files this will probably be fine.

`:cached` means that the host's files are authoritative, and the container won't constantly be checking for updates internally. This is usually ideal for code that you're editing on your host.